# Ubuntu 15.04 first use, not able to start using because unable to swipe

Tags: 15.04

I have used some older versions of Ubuntu, but am not expert with that. Now I wish to switch to Ubuntu completely. My problem is:

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 vivid-desktop-i386, downloaded from the official site. After installation and reboot, something shown like "ubuntu mobile" and some configuration windows for WiFi, pattern etc. Then, shown a screen to swipe from left, I did and then the guiding window shown another screen which tells "long swipe from right edge to see open apps". here is my problem, I am unable to do swipe!!

I am working on a Laptop, Dell Inspiron n4030, i3, 320HD, 2GB RAM.

Comment: No answer, but a question. Why you do not use the 64bit version?

Comment: If you do not necessarily need Ubuntu 15.04, then you should try it with Ubuntu 14.10. It may be that in Ubuntu 15.04 still some bugs are present, which may have something to do with your problem.

Comment: @A.B. is that 64 is for AMD?

Comment: when i installed 14.10, it was also having some bugs, that saying some package dependency error! so I waited for the next version, i was using 64 bit version, so I chosen 32 here!

Comment: No it is not. I have a Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8200 @ 2.66GHz and, no AMD processor, and 64-bit image is installed.

Comment: Package problems can be solved yet. ;c)

Comment: @A.B. It is often recommended to use a 32 bit operation system on systems with 2 gigabytes of memory or less as using a 64 bit version could cause performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the version 15.04 is not officially released yet (it is still an alpha, with a few bugs to be fixed), you should use one that is supported by now. Visit http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop (despite being a "desktop" version, it will work on your laptop - the desktop is the end-user version, contrary to the server version, that is made to work in servers, primarily). There you will find the option to download the 14.04 (supported until 2015) or 14.10 (supported until July). When the 15.04 is officially released, you will be able to upgrade form your version 14.xx to the stable 15.04 easily through System > Administration > Update Manager .